# TradingView Chart Library not working on production

Tags: reactjs, cryptocurrency, solana

I've implemented the TradingView charting library on my react project following the documentation provided.

> Copy charting_library folder from
> https://github.com/tradingview/charting_library/ to /public and to
> /src folders. Copy datafeeds folder from
> https://github.com/tradingview/charting_library/ to /public.

exactly as mentioned in the documentation , when i run yarn start it's working and showing however , when I build and try to serve it using nginx .
I get an error saying .

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'UDFCompatibleDatafeed').

```
import * as React from "react";
import "./index.css";
import {
  widget,
  ChartingLibraryWidgetOptions,
  IChartingLibraryWidget
} from "../../../charting_library";
import { useMarket, USE_MARKETS } from "../../utils/markets";
import * as saveLoadAdapter from "./saveLoadAdapter";
import { flatten } from "../../utils/utils";
import { BONFIDA_DATA_FEED } from "../../utils/bonfidaConnector";
import {} from "../../../charting_library";
export interface ChartContainerProps {
  symbol: ChartingLibraryWidgetOptions["symbol"];
  interval: ChartingLibraryWidgetOptions["interval"];
  auto_save_delay: ChartingLibraryWidgetOptions["auto_save_delay"];

  // BEWARE: no trailing slash is expected in feed URL
  // datafeed: any;
  datafeedUrl: string;
  libraryPath: ChartingLibraryWidgetOptions["library_path"];
  chartsStorageUrl: ChartingLibraryWidgetOptions["charts_storage_url"];
  chartsStorageApiVersion: ChartingLibraryWidgetOptions["charts_storage_api_version"];
  clientId: ChartingLibraryWidgetOptions["client_id"];
  userId: ChartingLibraryWidgetOptions["user_id"];
  fullscreen: ChartingLibraryWidgetOptions["fullscreen"];
  autosize: ChartingLibraryWidgetOptions["autosize"];
  studiesOverrides: ChartingLibraryWidgetOptions["studies_overrides"];
  containerId: ChartingLibraryWidgetOptions["container_id"];
  theme: string;
}


export interface ChartContainerState {}

export const TVChartContainer = () => {
  //  let datafeed = useTvDataFeed();
  const defaultProps: ChartContainerProps = {
    symbol: "BTC/USDC",
    // @ts-ignore
    interval: "60",
    auto_save_delay: 5,
    theme: "Dark",
    containerId: "tv_chart_container",
    //  datafeed: datafeed,
    libraryPath: "/charting_library/",
    chartsStorageApiVersion: "1.1",
    clientId: "tradingview.com",
    userId: "public_user_id",
    fullscreen: false,
    autosize: true,
    datafeedUrl: BONFIDA_DATA_FEED,
    studiesOverrides: {}
  };

  const tvWidgetRef = React.useRef<IChartingLibraryWidget | null>(null);
  const { market } = useMarket();

  const chartProperties = JSON.parse(
    localStorage.getItem("chartproperties") || "{}"
  );
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const savedProperties = flatten(chartProperties, {
      restrictTo: ["scalesProperties", "paneProperties", "tradingProperties"]
    });
    let newWindow :any = window ; 
    console.log("defaultProps.datafeedUrl", newWindow.Datafeeds);

    const widgetOptions: ChartingLibraryWidgetOptions = {
      symbol:
        USE_MARKETS.find(
          (m) => m.address.toBase58() === market?.publicKey.toBase58()
        )?.name || "SRM/USDC",
      // BEWARE: no trailing slash is expected in feed URL
      // tslint:disable-next-line:no-any
      // @ts-ignore
      // datafeed: datafeed,
      // @ts-ignore

      datafeed:new (window as any).Datafeeds.UDFCompatibleDatafeed(
        defaultProps.datafeedUrl,
      ),
      interval:
        defaultProps.interval as ChartingLibraryWidgetOptions["interval"],
      container_id:
        defaultProps.containerId as ChartingLibraryWidgetOptions["container_id"],
      library_path: defaultProps.libraryPath as string,
      auto_save_delay: 5,

      locale: "en",
      disabled_features: ["use_localstorage_for_settings"],
      enabled_features: ["study_templates"],
      load_last_chart: true,
      client_id: defaultProps.clientId,
      user_id: defaultProps.userId,
      fullscreen: defaultProps.fullscreen,
      autosize: defaultProps.autosize,
      studies_overrides: defaultProps.studiesOverrides,
      theme: defaultProps.theme === "Dark" ? "Dark" : "Light",
      overrides: {
        ...savedProperties,
        "mainSeriesProperties.candleStyle.upColor": "#41C77A",
        "mainSeriesProperties.candleStyle.downColor": "#F23B69",
        "mainSeriesProperties.candleStyle.borderUpColor": "#41C77A",
        "mainSeriesProperties.candleStyle.borderDownColor": "#F23B69",
        "mainSeriesProperties.candleStyle.wickUpColor": "#41C77A",
        "mainSeriesProperties.candleStyle.wickDownColor": "#F23B69",
        "background": "#141424        ",
        "backgroundColor" : "#141424 "
      },
      // @ts-ignore
      save_load_adapter: saveLoadAdapter,
      settings_adapter: {
        initialSettings: {
          "trading.orderPanelSettingsBroker": JSON.stringify({
            showRelativePriceControl: false,
            showCurrencyRiskInQty: false,
            showPercentRiskInQty: false,
            showBracketsInCurrency: false,
            showBracketsInPercent: false
          }),

          // "proterty"
          "trading.chart.proterty":
            localStorage.getItem("trading.chart.proterty") ||
            JSON.stringify({
              hideFloatingPanel: 1
            }),
          "chart.favoriteDrawings":
            localStorage.getItem("chart.favoriteDrawings") ||
            JSON.stringify([]),
          "chart.favoriteDrawingsPosition":
            localStorage.getItem("chart.favoriteDrawingsPosition") ||
            JSON.stringify({})
        },
        setValue: (key, value) => {
          localStorage.setItem(key, value);
        },
        removeValue: (key) => {
          localStorage.removeItem(key);
        }
      }
    };

    const tvWidget = new widget(widgetOptions);

    tvWidget.onChartReady(() => {
      tvWidgetRef.current = tvWidget;
      tvWidget
        // @ts-ignore
        .subscribe("onAutoSaveNeeded", () => tvWidget.saveChartToServer());
    });
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [market, tvWidgetRef.current]);

  return <div id={defaultProps.containerId} className={"TVChartContainer"} />;
};
function useTvDataFeed() {
  throw new Error("Function not implemented.");
}
```

ps: i've tried to implement this project : https://github.com/project-serum/serum-dex-ui

Comment: how did you resolve it